# How to loop not recursively over directories of directory with Ansible 2.x

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there an other way than this one to loop *not recursively* over directories of a directory at `root_dir`:

```
- name: loop over directories
  debug: var=item
  with_filetree: "{{root_dir}}"
  when: (item.path.split('/') | length == 1) and (item.state == 'directory')
```

Because this seems quite far-fetched, maybe there is a better way (that doesn't loop deeply over directories)?

Note: I also tried with a combination of `with_fileglob` and `item.state = 'directory'` but without success.

Edits:

- Using a bash command and then parsing it with Ansible (like `find` as @techraf proposed in comments, or `ls -l | grep '^d'`) can also answer the need but I was more asking for a use of an Ansible module different than `shell` or `command`.

Comment: If you worry about performance, maybe you should not use Ansible at all... I'm afraid you can only run `find` and parse the results.

Comment: I just try to use it with the best performances it can provide to me^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `command: find` with an argument to limit the search depth (afair, they differ in GNU and BSD's versions of `find`).

---

Or use two Ansible's native `find` tasks, both with `recurse: false`:

- first one: plain with `file_type: directory` in your `root_dir`
- second one: in a loop over the results of the first one with `paths: "{{ item }}"`

Because of a loop in the second task, you'll end up with results stored in a hierarchy, so to access flattened results use the following template (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517540/2947502)):

```
{{ second_task.results | sum(attribute='files', start=[]) | map(attribute='path') | list }}
```

You can add a third `set_fact`-task to simplify referring to the variable in subsequent tasks.